# Same lipo power source for raspberry pi and motor hat

Tags: power, hat

I am building a rover and would like to power the Raspberry Pi and the Motor HAT with the same power source.

I want to use a 2500 mAh LiPo battery for a long play time. My DC motors work at 6V-9V.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you add some more details to your question?  For example, which Pi?  Which hat?  Which motors?  What other electronics will be drawing power from this battery?

Answer (score 4):

You will quickly face 2 problems : voltage and current.

**Voltage**
You battery produce 3.7V, the Raspberry use 5V, your motor 6-9V.
You will basically needs [two DC-DC step-up voltage converter](https://www.amazon.fr/Renforcer-Convertisseur-Tension-Planche-R%C3%A9glable/dp/B06XWSV89D/ref=sr_1_14?ie=UTF8&qid=1509489165&sr=8-14&keywords=DC%20DC%20CONVERTER) to produce 5V and 9V from 3.7V.

**Current**
Now let's look if your supply provide enough current :
The raspberry pi3 needs 2.5A at 5V and the converter is said to have a 95% efficiency.

`0.95*(Ubat*Ibat)=Upi*Ipi`
`0.95*(3.7*2.5)=5*Ipi`
`Ipi=1.7575 A`

We can see that one battery is already not powerful enough for the raspberry (1.75A instead of 2.5A), so powering a motor on the same battery won't just work.

I don't know how other people solve this case, but you can look for lighter hardware that would limit the need of power (arduino ? rpi zero w?), or for bigger batteries.

Comment: The Lipo Battery is 11.1v

Answer (score -1):

Personally I would just use a UBEC and drive the Pi and the motors from the same 5V supply.  A UBEC converts a voltage in the range 6V to 26V to typically 5V and is what a lot of model airplane and quadcopter enthusiasts use.  Your motors should work from 5V.

Comment: Union of Banana Exporting Countries (UBEC) FTW.  That was DuckDuckGo's Wikipedia first result.  Maybe a brief explanation of what you mean by UBEC, what it is, and how you might use it in this case?

Comment: @YetAnotherRandomUser I understand your reasoning but am not minded to make a change.  Anyone who does not find the intended definition should not be using electricity!